# Left alignment of Bar chart axis labels

Tags: c#

I am trying to create a bar chart with axis labels that are left aligned having a specific distance to the plot. 
There seems to be neither an alignment function for axis labels, nor is it possible to insert a padding. The padding is ignored. What could be a solution for it:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Chart chart1 = new Chart();
        chart1.Size = new Size(600, 200);
        Title mainTitle = new Title("BarChartX");
        mainTitle.Alignment = ContentAlignment.TopLeft;
        mainTitle.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Arial", 11, FontStyle.Bold);
        chart1.Titles.Add(mainTitle);

        chart1.ChartAreas.Add(new ChartArea());
        chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.LabelStyle.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Arial", 10, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular);

        chart1.Series.Add("MySeries1").ChartType = System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.SeriesChartType.Bar;
        chart1.Series["MySeries1"].IsVisibleInLegend = false;
        chart1.Series["MySeries1"].Color = Color.Red;
        chart1.Series["MySeries1"].Points.AddXY(1, 1);
        chart1.Series["MySeries1"]["PixelPointWidth"] = "30";

        chart1.Series.Add("MySeries2").ChartType = System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.SeriesChartType.Bar;
        chart1.Series["MySeries2"].IsVisibleInLegend = false;
        chart1.Series["MySeries2"].Color = Color.Red;
        chart1.Series["MySeries2"].Points.AddXY(2, 2);
        chart1.Series["MySeries2"]["PixelPointWidth"] = "30";

        chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.MajorGrid.LineWidth = 0;

        chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Interval = 1;
        chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Interval = 2;
        chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Maximum = 3;
        chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Maximum = 6;

        Font stringFont = new System.Drawing.Font("Arial", 10, FontStyle.Regular);        /// !!!!!!!!!!!!

        string Label1 = "AxisLabel1".PadRight(12);
        chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.CustomLabels.Add(0.5, 1.5, Label1);

        string Label2 = "AxisLabel2";
        chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.CustomLabels.Add(1.5, 2.5, Label2);

        flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(chart1);

}[enter image description here][1]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While padding with space gets ignored/trimmed by the chart rendering engine, padding with a different white-space character like the non-breaking space does indeed work:

[image]

```
char space = (char)0xa0;
//..
string Label2 = "AxisLabel2".PadRight(12, space);
//..
string Label1 = "AxisLabel".PadRight(12, space);
//..
```

Of course, for the padding to work,  you need to switch to a mono-spaced font, like `Consolas`:

```
Font stringFont = new System.Drawing.Font("Consolas", 10, FontStyle.Regular);
```

**Update:**

There are several useful  [white-space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitespace_character) characters you may want to compare, most common:

- (char)0x00a0  no-break space
- (char)0x2002  en space
- (char)0x2003  em-break space
- (char)0x2008  punctuation space
- (char)0x2009  thin space
- (char)0x200A  hair space

Of course with Consolas or other mono-spaced fonts they all will have the same width.

OP commented that for him the only special character the worked was, strangely enough the [delete](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delete_character) character:

- (char)0x007f  delete character

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I couldn't make it work actually: 
>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
char space = (char)0xa0;
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.LabelStyle.Font = stringFont; 
string title1 = "AxisLabel1";
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.CustomLabels.Add(0.25, 0.75, title1.PadRight(12, space));
>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
It is still ignoring the space. Is there any setting I have to change except of the Font?

Comment: No other setting I believe.. - What font do you use? You should test in the windows character table tool to see if your font actually contains this special space character!c Consolas works as you can see..

Comment: It worked with 0x7F, that was the rigth direction to go, thank you very much!

Comment: 0x7F, really? That is the [Delete Character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delete_character), not a natural choice, imo.. Did the nbrsp (0xa0) not work for you?  - I'd like to update the answer to make it most useful for future SO users.. If you found the answer useful you may want to  consider [accepting](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) it..

Comment: No 0xa0 didn't work. I accepted the answer, thanks again